# How to change the base currency in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

Could you please help me with the following question?
How I can change the base currency in Acumatica?
I cannot fin a menu to do it.

Also, could you provide an example of API how to receive the base currency via API?

Answer (score 2):

Base Currency is set on the Companies(CS101500) page for the first Company in the Tenant and shared between all the Companies and can't be changed.
[image]

Comment: Samvel,

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Andrew,
To answer you're second question you will first need to create a Web Service Endpoint extension.
I have created one with this definition.

```
 <EntityEndpoint>
    <Endpoint xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="Extension" version="1" systemContractVersion="4" xmlns="http://www.acumatica.com/entity/maintenance/5.31">
        <ExtendsEndpoint name="Default" version="20.200.001" />
        <TopLevelEntity name="Company" screen="CS101500">
            <Fields>
                <Field name="BaseCurrencyID" type="StringValue" />
                <Field name="CompanyID" type="StringValue" />
                <Field name="CompanyName" type="StringValue" />
            </Fields>
            <Mappings>
                <Mapping field="BaseCurrencyID">
                    <To object="OrganizationView" field="BaseCuryID" />
                </Mapping>
                <Mapping field="CompanyID">
                    <To object="BAccount" field="AcctCD" />
                </Mapping>
                <Mapping field="CompanyName">
                    <To object="BAccount" field="AcctName" />
                </Mapping>
            </Mappings>
        </TopLevelEntity>
    </Endpoint>
</EntityEndpoint>
```

Once that is in place you can use the following to query the BaseCurrencyID
Robert

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost/CSO21_093_0135/entity/Extension/1/Company?$select=BaseCurrencyID'
```

Comment: Robert,

Thank you a lot!